# Auto creating model objects based on the relational model value

Tags: python, django

I have a model, which contains some fields, based on the one of the field value in the model, we need to create n number of objects in another model with default values.

I have a model called Room and it contains a field called number_of_beds based on that field we need to create n number of objects in anothe model called Bed.

```
Room(models.Model):
  room_no = IntegerField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
  number_of_beds = IntegerField()
  '''
  and so on
  '''

Bed(models.Model):
 room_no = models.ForeignKey('Room', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
 bed_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default='Increment value')
 '''
 and so on
 '''
```

if number_of_beds =2, need to create two objects in Bed with default values under the same ForeignKey.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what should be after update the `number_of_beds`? to large or to small number

Answer (score 1):

simple solution is override the `save`

```
Room(models.Model):
  room_no = IntegerField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
  number_of_beds = IntegerField()

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
      if self.number_of_beds > 0:
          for num in range(1, self.number_of_beds + 1):
              Bed.objects.get_or_create(room_no=self, bed_no=num)
      # clean extra beds
      self.bed_set.filter(bed_no__gt=self.number_of_beds).delete()
```